# Make File.nativePath bindable? or how to extend flash.filesystem.file

Tags: apache-flex, file, air

I would ultimately like to make .nativePath bindable or fire an event when it changes in Adobe Air. I figured I'd just extend the File class and be good.

But I cant find its source anywhere (so I know how to extend it). I've dug through http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/ quite a bit and didnt see anything.

Is there a way to make .nativePath bindable or extend File?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [File Class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2) is part of the Flash package, so it is not open source and you won't be able to get your hands on the code (unless you're deep in the inner circle of Adobe developers).

In theory you can extend the class, as it is not marked as final, and make the nativePath Bindable that way, but I'm not sure of the benefit.  You'd have to expand on your use case to evaluate that.

Comment: My plan was to have a couple of different items linked to myFile.nativePath. In particular, a label, a textInput and the source of a FileMonitor from as3corelib. A couple different functions can affect myFile, so I figured it'd be easiest to just bind other items to myFile.nativePath.

Answer (score 1):

alxx, your code was definitely close. Thank you - it gave me an idea on how to extend it. Working code:

```
public class FileEx extends File
    {
        public function FileEx(path:String=null)
        {
            super(path);
        }

        [Bindable("nativePathChanged")]
        override public function get nativePath():String
        {
            return super.nativePath;
        }

        override public function set nativePath(value:String):void
        {
            super.nativePath=value;
            dispatchEvent(new Event("nativePathChanged"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need source to subclass something. As long as it's not final, just extend it and override something you need:

```
public class BindableFile extends File {
    [Bindable(event="nativePathChanged")]
    override public function get nativePath():String {
        return super.nativePath;
    }
    override public function set nativePath(value:String):void {
        super.nativePath = value;
        dispatchEvent("nativePathChanged");
    }
}
```

Not tested, but looks realistic :)

Comment: If you extend a class and override a method; isn't that the same as subclassing?